# how to get 'excel' new lines in spreadsheetML (MSXSLT)

Tags: excel, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm using ms xslt 1.0 engine.

I want to generate an raw xml output like this:

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s27"><Data ss:Type="String">Catchup (Yes), &#10;FVOD(No), &#10;SVOD (No)</Data></Cell>
```

note the

```
&#10;
```

embedded in the output.

how do I get this in xslt?

If i do this:

```
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s27">
            <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:text>Catchup (Yes), </xsl:text>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&#10;]]></xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>SVOD (No)</xsl:text>
            </Data>
        </Cell>
```

I get this

```
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s27">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Catchup (Yes), &amp;#10;SVOD (No)</ss:Data>
    </ss:Cell>
```

which is wrong! (well, not what i want)

If I try

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
```

I get the same output

If I try the obvious

```
          <xsl:text>Catchup (Yes), &#10;SVOD (No)</xsl:text>
```

I get

```
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Catchup (Yes), 
SVOD (No)</ss:Data>
```

i.e. its a newline.

---

for others looking at this question, I'm not 100% sure what the question is, let alone the answer, and I'll try to clarify.

it seems that michael.hor257k's answer does work in some contexts.
(so in fact what im trying does work in some context)

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
```

this works if I hard code the output and run it in the XSLT engine used by VS2022

it doesnt work against my pretty 'vanilla' XSLT C# implementation against XSLTTransform and XSLTCompiledTransform.

I'm also not clear if it works with the VS2022 setup in my production code (which doesnt just hardcode some output, but does appytemplate and nodeset gynasmistics).

Comment: Why can't you simply hardcode the Cell element exactly as it is?

Comment: i'll add that to the question

Comment: tbh, I don't want to hardcode the output string, I want to delimit a nodeset with line feed chars

Comment: I still don't see the problem. The character `&#10;` **is** the LF character. It doesn't matter how it's represented in the output (and I doubt you have control over how it's represented with a MS processor).

Comment: no &#10; is a 6 character representation of LF...LF is LF...i.e. the character LF.
excel is expecting the 6 character representation of LF to be embedded inside the unparsed xml....it will ignore a LF character.

Comment: I don't know about Excel. In XML, the string `&#10;` is the exact equivalent of the LF character and a conforming parser will parse them the same. Anyway, your question is not about XSLT as such - it's about controlling the serialization of the transformation's result. And the answer is processor-dependent.

Comment: I agree that, my instinct is that excel is using some sort of non standard XML parsing, and what I'm asking for is a mechanism to generate potentially invalid xml BUT I had hoped that CDATA was that mechanism, but it seems that, at least with msxslt you can't force the serialised data - tbh, I think its a perfectly valid question. I'll try in Saxon maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really willing to resort to using `disable-output-escaping` to force the required result, consider the following example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Cell>
        <xsl:text>Alpha</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Bravo</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Charlie</xsl:text>
    </Cell>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Cell>Alpha&#10;Bravo&#10;Charlie</Cell>
```

However, this depends on the processor's support for `disable-output-escaping`. Judging from the examples in your question, the processor that you use does not. You say it's a Microsoft engine - but I do get the wanted result with both MS processors here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qLZFRw

Note also that `disable-output-escaping` is relevant only at the output stage. If you're not writing to the output, then it has no effect.

Comment: how very odd...I run this in visual studio (obviously againt msxslt engine)...and...it works!
I run it in C# code running the msxslt engine, and it it doesnt, it behaves like my code in my original example

Comment: As I said, an XSLT processor is not required to support `disable-output-escaping`. Perhaps in the configuration you are using the serialization is performed by another link in the processing chain.

Comment: its really odd though.....i'm serialising directly to a memory stream from the transform.

Comment: nope...there's something else going on that i don't understand, your answer DOES work given my simple example, but it doesnt work in my production code...I'll have to replicate, I'll mark this as an answer though

Comment: be interesting to know how the xsltfiddle code sets up its transforms, there's something odd going on...visual studio matched xslt fiddle but my pretty vanilla C# code doesnt, and this ms engnie is notoriously idiosyncratic

Comment: if you mention the fact the code needs to be on the output serialisation in 1.0, I'll mark this as the answer, at the moment it could be misleading.

Comment: I added a note to that effect. I think you are mistaken to think it's a version thing (the  "aberration" of XSLT 1.1 non-withstanding). Certainly not with a MS processor.

Comment: yeah u may be right, there's something weird going on though with my implementation

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a clarification. I believe this question has got nothing to do with [xslt](/questions/tagged/xslt), I added [excel](/questions/tagged/excel).

As michael.hor257k said, the two serializations (`&#10;` and a line-feed) should be equivalent. But when I open the following XML file with Excel

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="wrap">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Top"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Summary">
  <Table>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="wrap">
      <Data ss:Type="String">Catchup (Yes), &#10;FVOD (No), &#10;SVOD (No)</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="wrap"><Data ss:Type="String">Catchup (Yes), 
FVOD (No), 
SVOD (No)</Data>
     </Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

the two cells behave differently, although only in the Formula Bar:

[image]

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I see the same behavior in LibreOffice. Apparently neither LF nor `&#10;` are sufficient to properly restore the original in-cell line breaks. Interestingly, when I insert the line breaks manually and export the result, the values are separated by LF.

Comment: In-cell line breaks appear when you set the cells to "wrap text". But the difference in the Formula Bar remains.

Comment: see Michael Kay's answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75460450/how-to-get-excel-new-lines-in-spreadsheetml-and-the-behaviour-of-nodeset-on. The question is indeed relevant to XSLT, the XSLT spec, and XSLT engines, and to him at least a well known issue, if possibly not one that should be solvable in the language.

Comment: I can open the file in excel and the data is displayed differently between the 2 different encodings.

Comment: I don't see how "wrap text" is relevant here; I entered 3 values separated by command-return. Wrap Text is off for the cell, still all 3 values are displayed at all times (the entire row is 3 lines high).

Comment: With "wrap text", it looks so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIIXj.png

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd The issue (as presented by you) **is** solvable in the XSLT language; however, you must apply  the  `disable-output-escaping` at the output stage and not before, and you must use a processor that supports  `disable-output-escaping`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - actually fair enough, it is, its just that doesnt work for my context, but you're right.

Answer (score 0):

There was a follow up question with a marked answer.

[how to get 'excel' new lines in spreadsheetML and the behaviour of nodeset() on disable-output-escaping (Saxon xslt 1.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75460450/how-to-get-excel-new-lines-in-spreadsheetml-and-the-behaviour-of-nodeset-on)

Best read that, the summary is.

- the issue seems to be well know during specification of XSLT.
- the behaviour of "disable-output-escaping="yes"" changes between XSLT specs.
- the behaviour may well change between XSLT engines of the same theoretical spec (it certainly does for me between different MSXSLT engines/configs)
- "The issue is solvable in the XSLT language; however, you must apply the disable-output-escaping at the output stage and not before, and you must use a processor that supports disable-output-escaping" (michael.hor257k comment), for me the constaint on 'output stage' makes this correct solution unsuitable for my specific usage, but it is correct.

With an excel hat on, I've changed the implementation to export multiple rows rather than try to put multiple lines in a single cell.