# how to get 'excel' new lines in spreadsheetML and the behaviour of nodeset() on disable-output-escaping (Saxon xslt 1.0)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This is a follow up question to
[how to get 'excel' new lines in spreadsheetML (MSXSLT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75449973/how-to-get-excel-new-lines-in-spreadsheetml-msxslt)

but asked as a new question, to separate this into different issue, as the behaviour seems to be different between engines (I'll leave the specific context in the other question, this is purely how to achieve some functional result).

This XSLT (in saxon he) will create what I want.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <bar>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
            </bar>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and gives the output

```
<root>
   <bar>&#10;</bar>
</root>
```

this one wont:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="foo">
            <bar>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
            </bar>
        </xsl:variable>
        <root>
            <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($foo)"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it gives

```
   <bar>&amp;#10;</bar>
```

(the question is about XSLT 1.0 but interestingly XSLT 3.0 can be made to work like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="foo">
            <bar>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
            </bar>
        </xsl:variable>
        <root>
            <xsl:sequence select="$foo"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

whilst

```
        <xsl:copy-of select="$foo"/>
```

doesnt. Even following the 'sequence' pattern, I don't seem to be able to preserve non escaping in anything but a non trivial xslt - I've got a complex transformation using call-templates/apply-templates etc, and I think understanding how nodes are interpreted and serialised is not trivial)

Comment: Saxon HE but XSLT 1? With an XSLT 3 processor you have access to the serialize function and character maps. doe in a variable is not supposed to work.

Comment: the question is XSLT 1.0, I want to understand why it does/doesnt work with a bow an arrow, before using a rifle)

Comment: `disable-output-escaping` is relevant only at the output stage. If you're not writing to the output, then it has no effect.

Comment: I tend to chain transformations (in 1 stylesheet)....so I may generate some text in some initial document, that gets transformed through several more stages before being output. 
Even with the version that works in XSLT 3.0 it seems to, at some point, get escaped in an intermediary stage, I could probably work out where, but tbh, I'm just going to change the spec and abandon doing this....sadly it will be complex to get around

Comment: You've again asked two questions at once. I've answered one of them. It's better to keep questions separate.

Comment: well yes....the 2nd part is really because of others suggesting 3.0 and me trying to partially illustrate that in the question...guilty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a long history to this question, which was known in the working group as the "sticky d-o-e problem" (d-o-e being disable-output-escaping). The question is, does d-o-e have any effect when writing to a temporary tree (an xsl:variable), or is it only effective when writing to serialized output?

The XSLT 1.0 specification is pretty clear on the matter:

> It is an error for output escaping to be disabled for a text node that
> is used for something other than a text node in the result tree. Thus,
> it is an error to disable output escaping for an xsl:value-of or
> xsl:text element that is used to generate the string-value of a
> comment, processing instruction or attribute node; it is also an error
> to convert a result tree fragment to a number or a string if the
> result tree fragment contains a text node for which escaping was
> disabled. In both cases, an XSLT processor may signal the error; if it
> does not signal the error, it must recover by ignoring the
> disable-output-escaping attribute.

XSLT 2.0 deprecated d-o-e, but retained the rule in a slightly different form:

> This [property], however, can be set only within a final result tree
> that is being passed to the serializer.

But in between those two versions, the working group dithered. The XSLT 1.1 working draft (which never became a recommendation, but was popularised by the first version of my XSLT book) says:

> When a root node is copied using an xsl:copy-of element ... and
> escaping was disabled for a text node descendant of that root node,
> then escaping should also be disabled for the resulting copy of that
> text node. For example

```
<xsl:variable name="x">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:copy-of select="$x"/>
```

This is the "sticky d-o-e" - the d-o-e property is attached to the text node in the temporary tree and springs into life when the text node is eventually serialized. So this behaviour was endorsed at some stage in the life of XSLT, and you may be using a processor that implements this version of the spec.

Generally, though, try to forget that d-o-e exists. Whatever the problem, it's not the best solution. It's an incredibly messy feature because it requires a breaking of the architectural boundary between the transformation processor and the serializer, and breaking this boundary leads to close coupling of the transformation and serialization, and prevents you reusing the same code in a different pipeline configuration.

I'm afraid that researching the history of the W3C spec on this is rather easier than researching exactly what was implemented in early versions of Saxon (which are now nearly a quarter of a century old).

Comment: ok....the spec is clear to you...I'd have to think about it a bit, for a week or two - but I can completely understand the objection of allowing the transformer leak into the serialiser as being undesirable. If i were to apportion blame, it would be to MS for using this construct inside the spreadsheetML implementation of Excel. Thanks....I'm interpreting your answer as - try to avoid what I'm trying to achieve if at all possible.

Comment: actually I've done this by using a token for the LF in the excel generation but then using the copy template pattern and replacing this token with the "disable-output-escaping" encoded LF...and it miraculously works.
Thanks, your description of the spec and the 'result tree' was crucial to working around this horror.

Answer (score 0):

So to take the information from Michael Kay's answer which explains how the specification for XSLT 1.0 handles this, then we CAN implement a solution, for this.

So we take a recap of the underlying issue.

Excel spreadsheetML requires data to be formatted with the specific chars "
" to interpret a line feed in a cell (but this solution applies generally).

```
<Cell>Alpha&#10;Bravo&#10;Charlie</Cell>
```

If we try to write an XSLT to generate this, lets say naively:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Cell>
            <xsl:text>Alpha</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Bravo</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Charlie</xsl:text>
        </Cell>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

our &#10; will get delimited and we get this

```
<Cell>Alpha&amp;#10;Bravo&amp;#10;Charlie</Cell>
```

this (thanks to the answer on [how to get 'excel' new lines in spreadsheetML (MSXSLT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75449973/how-to-get-excel-new-lines-in-spreadsheetml-msxslt)) can be fixed by using

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Cell>
            <xsl:text>Alpha</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Bravo</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Charlie</xsl:text>
        </Cell>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which produces this:

```
<Cell>Alpha&#10;Bravo&#10;Charlie</Cell>
```

unfortunately this 'breaks' if you process your output document via some intermediary internal document e.g. even this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="output">
            <Cell>
                <xsl:text>Alpha</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>Bravo</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>Charlie</xsl:text>
            </Cell>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="msxsl:node-set($output)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

reverts to:

```
<Cell>Alpha&amp;#10;Bravo&amp;#10;Charlie</Cell>
```

because (see Michael Hay's answer) the disable-output-escaping attribute gets ignored if its passed through some internal document (i.e. the variable).

So...how can you get around this?

If you generate a token for the LF, you can then construct your psuedo excel output almost in its entirety except you use a custom element to flag the LF char, and then you can process that DIRECTLY into the result tree and interpret the custom element as an unescaped "&#10;"

so this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:kookerella="kookerella.com"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl kookerella">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="output">
            <Cell>
                <xsl:text>Alpha</xsl:text>
                <kookerella:LF/>
                <xsl:text>Bravo</xsl:text>
                <kookerella:LF/>
                <xsl:text>Charlie</xsl:text>
            </Cell>
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- process data directly into the result tree only --> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($output)" mode="injectLF"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Inject LF -->

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="injectLF">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="injectLF"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="kookerella:LF" mode="injectLF">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="injectLF"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

now results in:

```
<Cell>Alpha&#10;Bravo&#10;Charlie</Cell>
```

P.S.

as an aside, this seems to work for me in both the various MSXSLT and Saxon HE, but I have had an instance of using the MSXSLT engine where even this doesnt work, presumably due to some configuration out output serialisation issue.